# My png image is not displayed in the same size on my Android tablet depending on which code I use. The image looks much bigger in the splash screen

Tags: c#, android, xml

I use a 288x288 px png file "splash_logo" in my splash screen. But the image size on my Android tablet is different when I use .SetBackgroundResource to draw the image. When I use .SetBackgroundResource, then the image looks much smaller on the display and I don't understand why the image looks much bigger in the splash screen.

I want to draw the image with exactly the same size in the splash screen and afterwards with .SetBackgroundResource or similar code in Activity1.

Is it possible to draw the image with the same size in the splash screen and with .SetBackgroundResource in Activity1? Is it necessary to change something in the xml files so that the image is displayed in the same size?

In addition, which image size should I use for drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi? Should I use the same image 288x288 px png file in all these folders or is it better to use different sizes for the same image?

The file ic_splash_screen_image.xml is located in the folder Drawable:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
    <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
    </item>
    <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
    </layer-list>
```

The files colors.xml and styles.xml are located in the folder Values:

colors.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <resources>
    <color name="splash_background">#000000</color>
    <color name="custom_color">#4cb3fc</color>
    </resources>
```

styles.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <resources>
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
         <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
         <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent ="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_splash_screen_image</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/MainTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>
    </resources>
```

In Activity1.cs, I use the following code to draw the image:

```
    [Activity(
    Label = "@string/app_name",
    MainLauncher = true,
    Icon = "@mipmap/icon",
    Theme = "@style/SplashTheme",
    AlwaysRetainTaskState = true,
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.UserLandscape,         ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize
    )]

    public class Activity1 : AndroidGameActivity, ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalFocusChangeListener
    {

    FrameLayout layout;
    View splashView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
    AndroidX.Core.SplashScreen.SplashScreen.InstallSplashScreen(this);
    base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    layout = new FrameLayout(this.ApplicationContext);
    layout.AddView((View)_game.Services.GetService(typeof(View)));           
    splashView = new ImageView(this.ApplicationContext);
    ((ImageView)splashView).SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_splash_screen_image);
    layout.AddView(splashView);
    SetContentView(layout);
    }
    }
```

I have read this article but I don't understand why the image looks much bigger in my splash screen than drawn with .SetBackgroundResource in Activity1.cs:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Comment: The decision of how large the system-supplied splash screen image is will be determined by the device manufacturer. There is no guarantee of it being any particular size on any particular device screen. You have no reliable way of having any UI in your app be exactly the same size.